# Facebook Only Completes 1 Letter When I Type in Status or Messenger

Tags: facebook

[image: Not full sentences]

[image: FB Post]

This morning, I logged into Facebook and started communicating with some friends over Messenger when every sentence I typed and then hit enter, only 1 letter appeared in the Messenger window. I tried it in multiple windows but the same thing happened.

I also attempted to post a status in Facebook but the same thing happened, only 1 letter appeared.

To try and resolve this, I cleared cache/cookies, reset my browser to default and also rebooted but the issue persists. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I assume you're talking about an app. What platform? Unless you're in a web browser your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my browser from Internet Explorer to Google Chrome. That's fixed it.

That's why it still worked on my phone as it uses Safari.

Comment: Tried Chrome as well and there were now issues. It's working just fine now on IE11. Probably a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue this morning. I logged into FB and tried to send via FB Messenger from my computer (using Internet Explorer) and only the first letter I'm typing in messages box is being sent. my whole sentence is reflected in the typed box, but after hitting send, only the first letter is being displayed in the chat window. I'm not having the same issue with my Messenger app on my cell phone.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, then. Not much we can do about that.

Comment: Am using IE11 as well.